# Handle user interruptions in Bot Framework using Form Flow

Tags: botframework, bots, formflow

Can I handle user interruption in flormflow on certain question and them put user back to form to continue ?

Comment: What sort of interruption do you mean? Are you talking about the user saying something unrelated to the form?

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: Yes I need help sorry, the interruption i need is a human, like this:

1-BOT)  what is you name?
user: Jack
2-BOT) What is you age?
user: 25
3-BOT) What is you zip code?
user: well I dont know..... 
4-Redirect to human operator) Sir, please tell me you country, city and street so I can find your zip code.
user: Brazil, Rio de Janeiro, 34
5-Operator) You zip code is 02422-190
6-BOT) What is you zip code?
user: 02422-190
7-Next question......

Comment: Basically at some point I need to redirect the bot to a human and then go back to the formflow by following the stream

Comment: Is Helge Rene Urholm's answer acceptable?

Comment: no, I am still searching

Comment: Can you explain why Helge's answer isn't sufficient so we know how to help you?

Answer (score 1):

You may check out this: https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample

Mind the PRs for this project, if you need newer versions of everything. If using the newest versions you will need to build some nuget packages yourself: https://github.com/tompaana/bot-message-routing

And this last one also have PRs for latest versions of everything.

Yes, its a bit of a puzzle ;-), but you will be fine testing this out if not needing newest versions of everything.